# Getting the list of all players details using Google play leaderboard

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, leaderboard

I'm working with Google play leaderboards. But here I need to get list of all players details like name, rank, score, for this I'm using this code

```
 com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.Leaderboards.loadTopScores(GoogleApiClient apiClient, String leaderboardId, int span, int leaderboardCollection, int maxResults)
```

from the above line of code "maxResult" value is must between 1-25 (mentioned in this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards))

How can I get more than 25 results.

Answer (score 0):

The 1-25 value refers to the max results per page, you can add multiple pages for you leaderboards

> The maximum number of scores to fetch per page. Must be between 1 and
>   25.

Comment: Hi I finished this using "loadPlayerCenteredScores".